# The arguments "/S" and "/L" of the command ATTRIB won't work

Tags: cmd.exe, file-attributes

I'm creating a program where I need to make all folders and files, in a given directory, invisible. For that, I'm using the CMD's command `ATTRIB`, with the arguments `/S /D`, as well as in the code below:

```
ATTRIB +A +R +S +H "C:\Users\<user>\target" /S /D
```

However, these arguments are not working. Only the directory I pass in the command receives these attributes. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: if you give just one file/folder name, `attrib` processes just this one file or folder. You need a wildcard: `ATTRIB +A +R +S +H "C:\Users\<user>\target\*" /S /D`

Comment: @Stephan Thank you S2

Comment: Depending on the folder it will require ***run as admin***

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the attributes to the target folder **only**, to apply them to all files you need something like

`attrib path\*.* +a +r +h`

Add `/S` to apply the attributes to subfolders files recursively, the `/D` makes the attributes apply to folders too.